# Query: Employee Training Schedules Based on Position/Workrole

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

My company sends folks to training. Based on projected new hires/transfers, I was asked to generate a report that estimates the number of seats we need in each course broken out by quarter.

**Question:** My question is two-fold:

1. What is the best way to represent a sequence of courses (i.e. prerequisites) in a relational DB?
2. How do I create the query(-ies) necessary to produce the following desired output:

**Desired Output:**

```
ID    PersonnelID   CourseID    ProjectedStartDate   ProjectedEndDate
1               1          1             1/14/2017          1/14/2017
2               2          1             2/17/2017          2/17/2017
3               2          2             2/18/2017          2/19/2017
4               2          3             2/20/2017          2/20/2017
5               3         49             1/18/2017          2/03/2017
6              …
```

**Background Info:** The courses are taken in-sequence: the first few courses are orientation courses for the company, and later courses are more specific to the employee's workrole. There are over 50 different courses, 40 different workroles and we're projecting ~1k new hires/transfers. Each work role must take a sequence of courses in a prescribed order, but I'm having trouble representing this ordering and subsequently writing the necessary query.

**Existing Tables:**
I have several tables that I've used to store the data: `Personnel`, `LnkPersonnelToWorkroles`,`Workroles`, `LnkWorkrolesToCourses`, and `Courses` (there's many others as well, but I omit them for the sake of scoping this question down). Here's some notional data from these tables:

*Personnel* (These are the projected new hires and their estimated arrival date.)

```
ID  DisplayName       RequiredCompletionDate
 1  Kristel Bump                   10/1/2016
 2  Shelton Franke                 3/11/2017
 3  Shaunda Launer                 4/16/2017
 4  Clarinda Kestler               3/13/2017
 5  My Wimsatt                      6/6/2017
 6  Gillian Bramer                10/25/2016
 7   ...
```

*Workroles* (These are the positions in the company)

```
ID   Workrole 
 1   Manager
 2   Secretary
 3   Admin Asst.
 4   ...
```

*LnkPersonnelToWorkroles* (Links projected new hires to their projected workrole)

```
ID  PersonnelID WorkroleID
 1            1          1
 2            2          1
 3            3          1
 4            4          1
 5            5          1
 6            6          1
 7          ...
```

*Courses* (All courses available)

```
ID        CourseName   LengthInDays
 1       Orientation              1                
 2   Email Etiquette              2                
 3  Workplace Safety              1                
 4  ...
```

*LnkWorkrolesToCourses* 
(Links workroles to their required courses in a Many-to-Many relationship)

```
ID  WorkroleID   CourseID
 1           1          1
 2           2          1
 3           2          2
 4           2          3
 5           3         49
 6 ...
```

**Thoughts:** My approach is to first develop a person-by-person schedule based upon the new hire's target completion date and workrole. Then for each class, I could sum the number of new hires starting in that quarter.

I've considered trying to represent the courses in the most general way I could think of (i.e. using a directed acyclic graph), but since most of the courses have only a single prerequisite course, I think it's much easier to represent the prerequisites using the `Prerequisites` table below; however, I don't know how I would use this in a query.

*Prerequisites* (Is this a good idea?)

```
ID   CourseID  PrereqCourseID
 1          2               1
 2          3               1
 3          4               1
 4          5               4
 5 ...
```

Note: I am not currently concerned with whether or not the courses are actually offered on those days; we will figure out the course schedules once we know approximately how many we need each quarter. Right now, we're trying to estimate the demand for each course.

Edit 1: To clarify the *Desired Output* table: if the person begins course 1 on day D, then they can't start course 2 until after they finish course 1, i.e. until the next day. For courses with a length L >1 days, the start date for a subsequent courses is delayed L days. Notice this effect playing out for workrole ID 2 in the *Desired Output* table: He is expected to arrive on 2/17, start and complete course 1 the same day, begin course 2 the next day (on 2/18), and finish course 2 the day after that (on 2/19).

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer because it gives me an approximate solution; other answers are still welcome.

I avoided a prerequisite table altogether and opted for a simpler approach: a [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) of the courses.

First, I drew the course [prerequisite tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)); it looked similar to this image:

[image]

I defined a [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) of the courses based on their depth in the prerequisite tree. In the picture above, CHM124 and High School Chem w/ Lab are priority 1, CHM152 is priority 2, CHM 153 is priority 3, CHM260 and CHM 270 are priority 4, and so on... This partial ordering was stored in the `CoursePriority` table:

*CoursePriority:*

```
ID  CourseID    Priority
1   1           1
2   2           2
3   3           3
4   4           3
5   5           4
6   6           3
7   ...
```

So that no two courses would every be taken at the same time, I perturbed each course's priority by a small random number using the following Update query:

```
UPDATE CoursePriority SET CoursePriority.Priority = [Priority]+Rnd([ID])/1000;
```

(I used `[ID]` as input to the `Rnd` method to ensure each course was perturbed by a different random number.) I ended up with this:

```
ID  CourseID    Priority
1   1           1.000005623
2   2           2.000094955
3   3           3.000036401
4   4           3.000052486
5   5           4.000076711
6   6           3.00000535
7   ...
```

The approach above answers my first question "*What is the best [sensible] way to represent a sequence of courses (i.e. prerequisites) in a relational DB*?" Now as for generating the course schedule...

First, I created a query `qryLnkCoursesPriorities` to link `Courses` to the `CoursePriority` table:

```
SELECT Courses.ID AS CourseID, Courses.DurationInDays, CoursePriority.Priority
FROM Courses INNER JOIN CoursePriority ON Courses.ID = CoursePriority.CourseID;
```

Result:

```
CourseID    DurationInDays  Priority
1           35              1.000076177
2           21              2.000148297
3           28              3.000094352
4           14              3.000081442
5...
```

Second, I created the `qryWorkrolePriorityDelay` query:

```
SELECT LnkWorkrolesToCourses.WorkroleID, qryLnkCoursePriorities.CourseID AS CourseID, qryLnkCoursePriorities.Priority, qryLnkCoursePriorities.DurationInDays, ([DurationInDays]+Nz(DSum("DurationInDays","qryLnkCoursePriorities","[Priority]>" & [Priority] & ""))) AS LeadTimeInDays
FROM LnkWorkrolesToCourses INNER JOIN qryLnkCoursePriorities ON LnkWorkrolesToCourses.CourseID = qryLnkCoursePriorities.CourseID
ORDER BY LnkWorkrolesToCourses.WorkroleID, qryLnkCoursePriorities.Priority;
```

Simply put: The `qryWorkrolePriorityDelay` query tells me how many days in advance each course should be taken to ensure the new hire can complete all subsequent courses prior to their required training completion deadline. It looks like this:

```
WorkroleID  CourseID       Priority DurationInDays  LeadTimeInDays
         1         7    1.000060646              7             147
         1         1    1.000076177             35             140
         1         2    2.000148297             21             105
         1         4    3.000081442             14              84
         1         6    3.000082824             14              70
         1         3    3.000094352             28              56
         1         5    4.000106905             28              28
         2...
```

Finally, I was able to bring this all together to create the `qryCourseSchedule` query:

```
SELECT Personnel.ID AS PersonnelID, LnkWorkrolesToCourses.CourseID, [ProjectedHireDate]-[leadTimeInDays] AS ProjectedStartDate, [ProjectedHireDate]-[leadTimeInDays]+[Courses].[DurationInDays] AS ProjectedEndDate
FROM Personnel INNER JOIN (((LnkWorkrolesToCourses INNER JOIN (Courses INNER JOIN qryWorkrolePriorityDelay ON Courses.ID = qryWorkrolePriorityDelay.CourseID) ON (Courses.ID = LnkWorkrolesToCourses.CourseID) AND (LnkWorkrolesToCourses.WorkroleID = qryWorkrolePriorityDelay.WorkroleID)) INNER JOIN LnkPersonnelToWorkroles ON LnkWorkrolesToCourses.WorkroleID = LnkPersonnelToWorkroles.WorkroleID) INNER JOIN CoursePriority ON Courses.ID = CoursePriority.CourseID) ON Personnel.ID = LnkPersonnelToWorkroles.PersonnelID
ORDER BY Personnel.ID, [ProjectedHireDate]-[leadTimeInDays]+[Courses].[DurationInDays];
```

This query gives me the following output:

```
PersonnelID  CourseID   ProjectedStartDate  ProjectedEndDate
          1         7   5/7/2016            5/14/2016
          1         1   5/14/2016           6/18/2016
          1         2   6/18/2016           7/9/2016
          1         4   7/9/2016            7/23/2016
          1         6   7/23/2016           8/6/2016
          1         3   8/6/2016            9/3/2016
          1         5   9/3/2016            10/1/2016
          2...
```

With this output, I created a pivot table, where course start dates were grouped by quarter and counted. This gave me exactly what I needed.